# Building a 3D window manager for Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, window-managers

I'm looking to learn about Linux window managers and build my own. I have two requirements which I would like to employ: 3D support and good compatibility/performance with existing applications.

Are there any window managers that meet these criteria and are lightweight enough for me to work with?

If not, what do I need to take into account to implement 3D support myself? I see Xlib doesn't support 3D windows by default at all.

Edit: Xlib mentions XGetGeometry, which could get a windows pixmap. I could then display it myself using OpenGL, however, is this the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any window managers that meet these criteria and are lightweight enough for me to work with?

you could look at Compiz which does just that. Also it has a plugin architecture. However beware the pitfalls of X11 based compositing, the woes of X11 itself and that large portions of the Linux graphics community have drunken the Wayland Kool-Aid.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/). In a nutshell, Wayland gives each client a rectangular area to render things in and then builds the display on screen by compositing these areas.

The source code should give you some ideas how to redirect all the output of a client into a texture buffer.

Comment: Isn't Wayland still pretty unstable and unsupported though? There aren't very many examples to learn from either from the looks of it.

Comment: You can also try to figure out the same thing by looking at the KDE sources but they are much more complicated and you'll spend some time to even find out the interesting places for you. As for "unstable": 1.4 has been released a while ago. It took the team 2 years to get this far, which should give you an idea of the effort necessary to write a window manager for X.

Comment: The alternative would be [Mir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_(software)) but that's geared towards mobile devices and even more unstable.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Wayland is just a protocol and there's not a lot of support for end user programs out there. Yes in principle Wayland + Weston would enable OP to do what he wants. IMHO however Wayland is not a very good infrastructure for window management. It's too low level to be a sound foundations to build accelerated toolkits on (a lot of code duplication required, because clients are required to care about the characteristics of the output device). But then it's also too high level for a lightweight graphics driver infrastructure on which one could build a scalable display server.